# presentModalViewController - ViewController automatically disappears after presenting

Tags: iphone, ios, modalviewcontroller

I am currently developing an iPhone App for my company and i ran into a strange thing.

My View Hierachy looks like this:

UITabBarController containing 5 Tabs with every Tab containing a UINAvigationController.
So far everything works perfect.

Now i want to present a modal View controller via the presentModalViewController method on the
UITabBarController using this lines of code:

```
-(void)callFilterOptions
{
    FilterOptionsView *filterView = [[FilterOptionsView alloc] init];
    [filterView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:filterView animated:TRUE];
}
```

The FilterOptionsView is a normal UIViewController containing nothing but a black background at the
moment.

What happens is that the view is presented and after a couple of seconds misteriously disappears.
Why is this happening? At no Point i am calling the dismissModalViewController method.

I already ran into this problem when presenting a mailcomposer.

greetings,
Florian

Comment: Try changing self.tabBarController for [self.view presentModalViewController:filterView animated:TRUE];

Comment: The same error occurs. And i can not present the modal view controller from a View so i tried [self presentModalViewController:filterView animated:TRUE];

Comment: are you using ARC? try to make your filterView as a Class variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UINavigationController *myNavController = [self navigationController];
[myNavController presentModalViewController:filterView animated:TRUE];
```

or a better approach might be:

```
UIApplication *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
noIBAppDelegate*appDelegate = (noIBAppDelegate*)myApp.delegate;
[appDelegate.tabBarController presentModalViewController:filterView animated:YES];
```

to dismiss:

```
UIApplication *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
noIBAppDelegate*appDelegate = (noIBAppDelegate*)myApp.delegate;
[appDelegate.tabBarController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

p.s. I recommend not naming a view controller "filterView" it would be better named "filterViewController"

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far, but i found the solution.

[self.navigationController.tabBarController presentModalViewController:filterView animated:TRUE];
 That did the trick...

Comment: where in your structure is the callFilterOptions method? in a view controller?

Comment: the method is on a ViewController which is insede the NavigationController which is in the TabBarController.